# "house owner" vs. "householder"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/householder)

> householder: the person who owns or is in charge of a house

Suppose Anthony just bought a house, I guess he is always the owner of the house in the following contexts.

## context 1

When Anthony rents the house to Kevin, is Kevin the householder? Is Anthony still the householder?

## context 2

When Anthony hires Kevin as his housekeeper, is Kevin the householder? Is Anthony still the householder?

Are there any other contexts where someone else could be the householder?

Comment: Americans have pretty much switched over to ***homeowner***, but apparently that shift [hasn't really happened yet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+householder%2Cthe+homeowner&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20householder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20homeowner%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20householder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20homeowner%3B%2Cc0) in British English. But I'm a Brit, and I'd nearly always use ***homeowner*** rather than ***householder***, so I was a bit surprised to see that US/UK usage split in NGrams

Comment: A house**holder** is someone who occupies a home, either as owner or enter, etc. A house**keeper** is an employee or servant who provides domestic servant support to the householder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oxford Dictionaries defines *householder* as  *a person who owns or rents a house; the head of a household.*

So in (1), Kevin is the householder and Anthony his landlord.

On (2), if Kevin is a live-in housekeeper, it is Anthony's household.

Comment: Thank you. In (2), who is the householder?

Comment: By 'it's Anthony's household,' I meant that he is the householder.